# How to get an Elasticsearch aggregation with multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, faceted-search

I'm attempting to find related tags to the one currently being viewed. Every document in our index is tagged. Each tag is formed of two parts - an ID and text name:

```
{
    ...
    meta: {
        ...
        tags: [
            {
                id: 123,
                name: 'Biscuits'
            },
            {
                id: 456,
                name: 'Cakes'
            },
            {
                id: 789,
                name: 'Breads'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

To fetch the related tags I am simply querying the documents and getting an aggregate of their tags:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "item.meta.tags.id": "123"
                    }
                },
                {
                    ...
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "baked_goods": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "item.meta.tags.id",
                "min_doc_count": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, I am getting the results I want. However, I require both the tag ID *and* name to do anything useful. I have explored how to accomplish this, the solutions seem to be:

1. Combine the fields when indexing
2. A script to munge together the fields
3. A nested aggregation

Option one and two are are not available to me so I have been going with 3 but it's not responding in an expected manner. Given the following query (still searching for documents also tagged with 'Biscuits'):

```
{
    ...
    "aggs": {
        "baked_goods": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "item.meta.tags.id",
                "min_doc_count": 2
            },
            "aggs": {
                "name": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "item.meta.tags.name"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I will get this result:

```
{
    ...
    "aggregations": {
        "baked_goods": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "456",
                    "doc_count": 11,
                    "name": {
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": "Biscuits",
                                "doc_count": 11
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "Cakes",
                                "doc_count": 11
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The nested aggregation includes both the search term *and* the tag I'm after (returned in alphabetical order).

I have tried to mitigate this by adding an `exclude` to the nested aggregation but this slowed the query down far too much (around 100 times for 500000 docs). So far the fastest solution is to de-dupe the result manually.

What is the best way to get an aggregation of tags with both the tag ID and tag name in the response?

Thanks for making it this far!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

By the looks of it, your `tags` is not `nested`.
For this aggregation to work, [you need it `nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) so that there is an association between an `id` and a `name`. Without `nested` the list of `id`s is just an array and the list of `name`s is another array:

```
    "item": {
      "properties": {
        "meta": {
          "properties": {
            "tags": {
              "type": "nested",           <-- nested field
              "include_in_parent": true,  <-- to, also, keep the flat array-like structure
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "name": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Also, note that I've added to the mapping this line `"include_in_parent": true` which means that your `nested` tags will, also, behave like a "flat" array-like structure.

So, everything you had so far in your queries will still work without any changes to the queries.

But, for this particular query of yours, the aggregation needs to change to something like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "baked_goods": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "item.meta.tags"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "item.meta.tags.id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "name": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "item.meta.tags.name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the result is like this:

```
   "aggregations": {
      "baked_goods": {
         "doc_count": 9,
         "name": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": 123,
                  "doc_count": 3,
                  "name": {
                     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                     "buckets": [
                        {
                           "key": "biscuits",
                           "doc_count": 3
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": 456,
                  "doc_count": 2,
                  "name": {
                     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                     "buckets": [
                        {
                           "key": "cakes",
                           "doc_count": 2
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               .....
```

Comment: @i_like_robots I'm curious, have you tested my suggested solution?

Comment: he decided to keep the bounty for himself, thank you for the good answer!

Comment: In the end, yes! We were eventually able to spend the time creating a new index with properly nested fields but I'm afraid it wasn't until very recently. Thank you for your time answering my question and I apologise for neglecting any Stack Overflow etiquette!

Comment: The "string" field is now deprecated. Check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#before-enabling-fielddata for using a text/keyword combined field.